# Hinduism on sexual desire and its conceptualisation

Tags: scripture, sex, desire

Hinduism seems to be the oldest supporter and spreader of Celibacy. But as far as my little readings are concerned, Hinduism doesn’t distinguish the sexual desire from other material desires, it just talks about all human desires and asks the believer to renounce it (but doesn’t tell how).

I’m looking for something, something original like **Vedas**, **Shri MadBhagvatam**, **Puranas** where celibacy is delineated. Hinduism talks about the senselessness of the body, it says sex desire is the desire of want of body but body is unreal and is made up of all the bad material things one shouldn’t go after them, I want a detailed view of Hinduism on sexual desires and how the ancient sages attained celibacy (I think the sage **Vishwamitra** once got seduced by a heavenly singer).

What Hinduism has to say about body and sexual desire? Does it have the same concept (with different words) that it’s all about dopamine and release of good-feeling hormones during orgasm?

Answer (score 2):

Hinduism accepts that sexual desire is quite natural but at the same time suggests that restraining or curbing that desire bestows great merits.

> Manu Smriti 5.56. There is no sin in eating meat, in (drinking)
> spirituous liquor, and in carnal intercourse, for that is the natural
> way of created beings, but abstention brings great rewards.

Hinduism also accepts the fact that lust is extremely powerful and it is capable of deviating even the sages from their paths of restraint.

> 2.215. One should not sit in a lonely place with one’s mother, sister, or daughter; for the senses are powerful, and master even a learned
> man.

Sexual desire (Kama) is in fact counted among one of the [Shadaripus (Arishadvargas)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arishadvargas), the six enemies or obstacles in the path of spiritual progress.

Comment: Your answer is good, but I’m looking for a deeper discourse than that.

Comment: More details won't be found in traditional Hindu scriptures. For that one may have to look into books like Kamasutra or treatises on Ayurveda @ConGovDeIn